# What are alternatives for Sinon.js (JS mocking library)?

Tags: unit-testing, sinon

Are there any worthwhile alternatives for Sinon.js?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for asking: Did you Google for "javascript mock"? Or are you asking, "what is your favourite mocking library"? Subjective answers guaranteed.

Comment: So you're looking for _alternatives,_ not "analogs."

Comment: Yes alternatives. Right.) Thank you for correction .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite as advanced, but you can look at [Jack](https://github.com/keronsen/jack).

Comment: Yeah, it definitely is the best Javascript mocking library at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

## Testdouble.js

There is also library called [testdouble.js](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js). Which is a kind of more object-oriented than sinon.js.

Also, [this article](http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2016-03-13-testdouble-vs-sinon.html) from testdouble guys explain the differences between sinon.js and testdouble.js.

## Example

```js
var td = require('testdouble');

var fetch = td.function();
td.when(fetch(42)).thenReturn('Jane User');

fetch(42); // -> 'Jane User'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started a new project called candy-wrapper that may be an alternative to Sinon in some instances:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/candy-wrapper

Here are some examples of how to use it, I would love feedback if anyone has any insights as to how to make it better:

```js
var Wrapper = require("candy-wrapper");

// a simple test object
var myDrone = {
    name: "DJI",
    fly: function(direction) {
        return true;
    }
}

new Wrapper(myDrone, "name");
new Wrapper(myDrone, "fly");

myDrone.fly("north");
myDrone.fly("west");

// evaluating previous calls through the 'historyList' and 'Filters'
myDrone.fly.historyList.filterFirst().expectCallArgs("north"); // true
myDrone.fly.historyList.filterSecond().expectCallArgs("east"); // false
myDrone.fly.expectReportAllFailtures(); // throws an error about the "east" expecation failing

// modifying behavior using 'Triggers'
myDrone.fly.triggerOnCallArgs("east").actionReturn(false); // will return 'false' when called with "east"
myDrone.fly("east"); // false
myDrone.fly("west"); // true (the default return value)

// working with properties
myDrone.name.triggerOnSet().actionThrowException(new Error("do not set the name"));
myDrone.name = "Bob"; // throws Error: "do not set the name"
var ret = myDrone.name; // ret = "DJI"
```